# How to substring a certain string using variables as indexes in a batch program

Tags: batch-file, substring

I'm trying to substring a certain string using variables as indexes:

```
call :subStrFunction 0 1 test

:subStrFunction
set _startchar =%~1
set _endchar =%~2
set _stringInput=%~3

::tried with this
CALL SET subStr=!_stringInput:~%_startchar%,%_endchar%!

::and this (found on http://ss64.com/)
::CALL SET subStr=%%_stringInput:~%_startchar%,%_endchar%%%

::end this
::SET _substring=%_stringInput:~%_startchar %,%_endchar %


echo substring %subStr%
```

but none of them works >,<

Thx in advance! :D

**UPDATE: SOLVED** by adding `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: try to with replaced `set _startchar = %1%` to `set "_startchar=%~1` and so on for the next two.

Comment: `set "_startchar=%~1"` *

Comment: which call should i use then?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Just `%1%` is not the first argument - arguments have percentage only at the front . and `%~1` meand the first argument without quotes.

Comment: yep, i made an error there, but still the substring command it's not working.
i updated the parameter assignement code. Thx for pointing out.

Comment: put this line right after `:subStrFunction`  . `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion`  . You need delayed expansion here.

Comment: It now works. Thanks

Comment: You are definitely on the right track.

Comment: The different ways to achieve this management is described at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Comment: @Koop4 If my answer works, then please accept it; batch files don't write themselves...

Answer (score 1):

I reworked the batch file to allow for either 1 or both parameters for the sub-string feature.

The turn value will be stored in an environment variable called {str_Return} and will be visible outside of the setlocal environment.
A second environment variable called {bolReturn} will be set to {T} for a successful result and {F} if at least the start position was not supplied or there was an error with the sub-string command.

```
@Echo Off
call :subStrFunction test 0 1

If "%bolReturn%" EQU "T" (
Echo %str_Return%
) Else (
Echo Command was not successful
)
pause

:subStrFunction
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
REM String variable needs to be first
set stringInput=%~1
REM If only 1 number is given
If "%~2" EQU "" Goto :l_Missing_Param
If "%~3" EQU "" Goto :l_1_Operand

REM Start and stop parameters given
Set "str_Result=!stringInput:~%~2,%~3!"
If [%ERRORLEVEL%] NEQ [0] Goto :l_Exeuction_Error
Goto :l_Return_Value

:l_1_Operand

REM Start parameter given
Set "str_Result=!stringInput:~%~2!"
If [%ERRORLEVEL%] NEQ [0] Goto :l_Exeuction_Error
Goto :l_Return_Value

:l_Missing_Param
Echo.
Echo You did not provide the correct number of parameters

REM Set Exit value to F for an imcomplete execution
EndLocal & Set bolReturn=F
Goto :EOF

:l_Exeuction_Error
Echo.
Echo An unspecified error has occured!

REM Set Exit value to F for an imcomplete execution
EndLocal & Set bolReturn=F
Goto :EOF

:l_Return_Value
REM Store result value in stable variable
EndLocal & Set "str_Return=%str_Result%"

REM Set Exit value to T for a complete execution
Set bolReturn=T
Goto :EOF
```

You can either use this as a sub-routine or for a seperate batch file entirely.

p.s. If you copy this code into your own batch file, make very sure that each quote {"} used is an actual quote and not one of the curly quotes or the batch file will fail.

Comment: it sounds like an overkill xD
By the way i appreciate your effort. I'll try to wade in it to learn something! :D